# Android Studio Project SDK Path Mac VS Windows

Tags: android, sdk, path, android-studio

I use 2 machines for development, Windows 8 desktop and a Macbook for when I'm away from my desk. I use dropbox to sync my development files between 2 machines. This works pretty well, except for one thing: the SDK path must be updated every time (http://screencast.com/t/XKnqUjiBn)

Is there a work around of some sort for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't share the **local.properties** file between machines; that's the file that contains the SDK path, and as its filename indicates, it's supposed to be local to an individual machine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take a look at a GIT source control (if you haven't done that previously). It is the way better way to manage projects than dropbox sync.

There are 2 very good options for you:

- GitHub - free for open source projects, paid for private repositories (paid per repository)
- BitBucket - free for private repos too (paid per user)

AndroidStudio (which I suggest for Android projects unless you are working with NDK) has a really good support for importing projects to GIT via GUI. So it helps you a bit if you are not familiar with console stuff. But it is easy with console too. Check out this github tutorial for beginners https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

With GIT the problem that you are trying to solve is simple just put a file name that you dont want to share into you gitignore file. You can find android preset gitignore files online on sites like gitignore.io.

Good luck.